# Access data on a different server within python script

Tags: python, server, remote-access

I need to process huge amounts of data files stored on another server. How can I do this in python? My script looks like `ds = ds.load('__local_path__')` Can I do something like `ds = ds.load('my_login@remote_server:/path_to_files')`
?

Comment: Have you ever considered to use FTP to get the files?

Comment: the files are too large for that. We're talking about roughly 1.3 TB. That's more than I have available on my local drive

Comment: Is there any protocol in your mind to this rather than FTP(File Transfer Protocol). FTP file transfer size limit is depends on your FTP server's configuration. On the other hand what is the reason for working with a 1.3TB file remotely.

Comment: I think I missunderstood your first comment. I thought you meant fetching the files via any FTP client and then running the script over it, but now I discovered python's `ftplib` library. I'll try it with that.
FYI: There are ~1000 files from a simulation, each 1 GB, located on the cluster were I calculated them. I'm not allowed to install new packages on the cluster, so I can't process them there directly

Comment: Okay, `ftplib` doesn't seem to work, the server only allows SFTP access.

Comment: Could you update the question and include the progress that you have made?

Comment: had to work on a different topic and haven't made any progress yet. will update it when I'm back on it, probably on Saturday

Comment: OK I will be waiting